# How to install documentation for 7zip4PowerShell

Tags: powershell

After installing the 7zip4PowerShell module, if I call `Get-Help` on any of its cmdlets, I get the message

```
Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
    -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
```

If I call `update-help` by itself, it doesn't change anything.

If I call `update-help -Module 7zip4PowerShell`, I get the following:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> update-help -Module 7zip4PowerShell
update-help : Failed to update Help for the module(s) :
'7Zip4Powershell'
The HelpInfoURI https://github.com/thoemmi/7Zip4Powershell does not start with HTTP.
At line:1 char:1
+ update-help -Module 7zip4PowerShell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (HelpInfoUri:Uri) [Update-Help], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidHelpInfoUriFormat,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateHelpCommand
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same issue for me. I found this but can't tell if it's the exact same issue: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/3845110e-b234-431e-bf7a-75b15aae8d9a/updatehelp-cmdlet-not-able-to-update-the-help-with-https-protocol?forum=winserverpowershell